# Redirect From Action Filter Attribute Throws Exception “Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent”

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, asp.net-web-api-routing

Action Filter Attribute:

```
public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        Controller controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;
        if (controller != null)
        {
            if (tokenContainer.ApiToken == null)
            {
                filterContext.Canceled = true;
                controller.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("./Login");
            }
        }
    }
```

it throws an exception when trying to redirect to Login Action.

Comment: You need to override [OnActionExecuting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.actionfilterattribute.onactionexecuting(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: How to implement this? @mmushtaq

Comment: Just change method name `OnResultExecuted` with `OnResultExecuting` like this `public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext){....}` .

Comment: Not working also

Comment: what errors you are facing now?

Comment: 'AuthenticationAttribute.OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext)': no suitable method found to override.

Comment: @azzaali can you try this before redirecting `controller.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Clear();`

Comment: Not Working @Usman

Comment: @azzaali actually in my last comment i have a typo. Please override `OnResultExecuting` .. `public override void OnResultExecuting`..

Comment: already i have changed to "OnResultExecuting" , but not working. @mmushtaq

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, according to [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.110).aspx), `Response.Redirect("url")` throws HttpExeption when

> A redirection is attempted after the HTTP headers have been sent

So you can check the `Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected` property (bool) before calling it.

Like :

```
// Causes headers to be sent to the client (Http "Location" response header)
Response.Redirect("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
if (!Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected)
 // Will not be called
 Response.Redirect("URL");
```

Comment: i tried this but it gives me error how i can use this according to my function @Francois

Comment: It's not redirect to login , it throws exception “Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent”

Comment: How I can use your example? @Francois Borgies

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to redirect.  Set the Result of the `ActionExecutingContext` to route you where you want to go.

You want something like this:

```
public class CustomSecurityAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (tokenContainer.ApiToken != null) return;

        //this will re-route you action
        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "Login",  //whatever view you are routing to
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model), //you can leave it blank if your view doesn't need data
            TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
        };
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    }
}
```